# Percent-encoding in an URI

Tags: java, android, browser, httpservice

I would like to know how can I convert URI:

```
%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA
```

to

```
русский язык
```

I know about `urldecode` function in PHP. I'm looking for the same function in Java(Android). Could anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29).. may be helpfull.. its a straight forward thing..

```
Uri.decode("%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA");
```

Answer (score 5):

I've found answer:

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URI)
```